# getting return value from function?

Tags: javascript

```
function remove(){
    console.log(xxx());
    if(xxx() != true){
        console.log(xxx());
        return;
    }

    console.log('removed');
}

function xxx(){
    SweetAlert.swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55"},
        function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

How to get return from function `xxx()`.

That's always return undefined when i fire remove().

If return is true i want to do `console.log('removed')`.

Comment: please check this http://oitozero.github.io/ngSweetAlert/ 5'th example

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: thats example is using with ajax, im still not understood, can u please explain with case above :)

Comment: `SweetAlert.swal` accepts a *callback* function. You can't return a value from a callback function to a parent function like that - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) maybe explains it better, but you need to approach by adding your own callback

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your calling function has no access to the result of the callback function, however you can supply your wrapper `xxx` function with your own callback to be passed. Therein you have the choice of supplanting the callback entirely or for example pass only the action to be undertaken on success:

```
function remove(){
    xxx(function(){console.log('removed');});
}

function xxx(OnSuccess){
    SweetAlert.swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55"},
        function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm && OnSuccess) 
                OnSuccess();
        }
    );
}
```